# Column filter by VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I want to filter date column with VBA code but im getting wrong results.

My data (example only, I have many rows):

```
complete_date
(blank)
(blank)
(blank)
(blank)
(blank)
(blank)
5/12/18 9:08 AM
5/12/18 9:41 AM
5/20/18 1:51 PM
(blank)
(blank)
(blank)
(blank)
5/20/18 1:50 PM
5/20/18 1:52 PM
5/21/18 6:35 AM
5/20/18 1:49 PM
5/20/18 1:54 PM
5/21/18 7:53 AM
5/20/18 1:49 PM
5/20/18 1:56 PM
5/21/18 11:20 AM
5/20/18 1:49 PM
```

My code:

```
Public Sub MyFilter()
    Dim lngStart As Long, lngEnd As Long
    lngStart = Range("b1").Value 'assume this is the start date
    lngEnd = Range("b2").Value 'assume this is the end date
    Range("q:q").AutoFilter field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & lngStart, _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:="<=" & lngEnd
End Sub
```

For this example if im filtering according below dates im not getting all possible results ( I do not see any results from 5/20 day).
My search:

5/20/18 13:51  ---> start time
5/22/18 13:51  ---> end time

Any idea why? Thanks,

Comment: Dates in autofilter **must** be in U.S. format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparisons should be made between dates, not strings, assuming that your column `Q` and the 2 input cells are formatted as a date

just change your code to

```
Dim lngStart As date, lngEnd As date
```

Comment: I think you had posted this question earlier and before I could answer it, you removed it.

Comment: Yes, yesterday I though I fix it so I remove it. Thanks anyway and thanks for the fast resound.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `lngStart` and `lngEnd` as `Long` which is a whole number - so the time element of your parameters is ignored, and datetimes > 12:00pm are 'rounded' up to the next day.

Change these to type `Double` and your code works as intended:

```
Public Sub MyFilter()
    Dim dStart As Double, dEnd As Double
    dStart = Range("b1").Value 'assume this is the start date
    dEnd = Range("b2").Value 'assume this is the end date
    Range("q:q").AutoFilter field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & dStart, _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:="<=" & dEnd
End Sub
```

Comment: That code snippet doesn't work with the variables declared as `Date` when the dates are in UK `dd/mm/yyyy` format, without further processing of date format to pass to the filter. Excel treats dates as a number, so using the `Double` data type safely ignores the local date format.